# Dragging and Dropping Jquery functionality not working in controller.js after loading Jquery libraries in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, lightning

I have a requirement in lightning to drag & drop records to multiple divs from a list of records.
I tried to implement it using jquery in Lightning,I am facing issue in loading the jquery libraries and calling the Draggable and Droppable interactions in Controller.js

I am able to achieve this functionality in Classic.

I have a couple of queries in loading external libraries and how to make jQuery work in lightning.

Please correct the syntax if I am going wrong.
calling Jquery Libraries.

jquery224 -- jquery.2.2.4 version
jquery12 -- jquery 1.12 version

I am getting the error: (Jquery not defined / apply not defined ) on loading.

which version of jquery loads correctly in lightning?

how to call a draggable and droppable function in controller.js,If I am using the below code I am getting an error $ not defined.

```
$(function() {
        $(".draggable").draggable();   
        $( "#droppable").droppable({  
            drop: function( event, ui ) {  
                $( this )  
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )  
                .find( "p" )  
            }  
        });   
   })
```

Please provide some code sample's if anyone has worked similarly.

Comment: Have you ever solved this?